# error: Failed to run the post merge process

Tags: apex

I'm trying to generate documents using conga composer 8 from apex code but its failing with error  `Failed to run the post-merge process`. I have looked into url and its same as the one I used initially in another salesforce org. I couldn't find any help online or on conga-composer form.

Here is my conga endpoint URL:

```
https://composer.congamerge.com/Composer8/Index.Html? sessionId=00D41000000dorw!ARQAQKbinH5TXMR_70s3XCShQh5GuSVdrFcq0Fg9OidZLo9MLxzWSby8QY1B4xM8e72DPawVziclnXBjTzpG41RiCAPKQqOt
&serverUrl=https://na35.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0/00D41000000dorwEAA
&id=a1J410000012BwS
&TemplateId=a0C41000000kg5GEAQ
&APIMODE=13
&ESAgreementName=Contract+for+Test
&queryid=a0441000001PwI7AAK,a0441000001PwICAA0
&ESSignatureType=2
&ESSignatureOrder=2
&ESVisible=1
&ESCustomField=cldocgen__App__c
&ESCustomFieldValue=a1J410000012BwSEAU
&ESRecipient1=00541000000Ke9pAAC
&ESRecipient2=003410000078zVbAAI
&ESRecipient3=003410000078zVhAAI, Method=GET]
```

Any insight what might be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it using permissions.  In this case make sure the user id whose sessionID is passing to Conga has the correct CRUD access to the primary object in your conga call (id=a1J410000012BwS).  My guess is that this is something to do with Conga not being able to write the attachment back to salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Greg has mentioned, there are 2 more observations for this error:

1. Under Email Administration -> Deliverability -> Access to Send Email (All Email Services) should be set to All email.
2. In case you are using the [EmailTemplateId](https://support.conga.com/content/composer/composer-parameter-guide/emailtemplateid) parameter then the classic email template must be available for use.

Also mostly this error is also because of some discrepancy in the URL.